# Unknown Sender or different email address in email header

Tags: php, contact-form

I am trying to setup a new contact form.  I am able to receive the email and the message correctly, but the reply-to is either showing up as (unknown sender) or my username at my nameserver, ex: coggi132@rs14.websitehostserver.net.  I've looked at this for 4 hrs now, removing and adding in differnet things I've seen online.  It does work if I hardcode an email address into the mail(..."$visitor_email") section.  Thanks

Here is the html:

```
<form id="form" action="../assets/form-to-email.php" method="post">
    <p><label class="required" for="namet">Name</label>(required)<br /><input name="name" id="name" type="text" required/>
<input type="text" style="display:none;" id="zip" name="zip" placeholder="Leave this field blank" autocomplete="off"></p>
    <p><label class="required" for="mailt">E-mail</label>(required)<br /><input name="email" id="email" type="text" required/></p>
    <p><label for="phone">Phone</label><br /><input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" required/></p>
    <p><label class="required" for="message">Message</label>(required)<br /><textarea name="message" id="message" required></textarea></p>
    <p><input class="btn_m" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" /></p>
</form>
```

Here's the php

```
<?php
/*
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}*/
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$email_subject = "New Message From NovaWebDev.com Form";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from $name.\n
Phone Number: $phone \n
Here is the message: $message \n".

$to = "info@novawebdev.com";//<== Website's email address
$headers = "From: $visitor_email \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body, $headers);
//done. redirect to success page.
header('Location: /index.php/shared/email_success');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
          '(\r+)',
          '(\t+)',
          '(%0A+)',
          '(%0D+)',
          '(%08+)',
          '(%09+)'
          );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: you dont use your `$headers` and `$visitor_email` is not a valid mail header

Comment: I changed it back to $headers and I get (unknown sender) as the reply-to email

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code (*tested*). Since you haven't posted your form, make sure your Email's form input is named. I.e.: `<input type="text" name="email">` which is most likely the case.

Comment: I made those changes to the button, no luck.  Also, I had to add that missing php back that got deleted when I edited/added the html.  Still unknown sender.  Thanks

Comment: Ok, I tested this *again* as per your complete edit and there's nothing wrong with it. Are you sure those are indeed the files you're using and that you uploaded the latest versions of them?

Comment: Fred, thanks.  It always "Worked", but I did not see the reply-to email.  The input field was named mail, but named email in my php.  Thanks

Comment: @C.Coggins You're welcome. I'm just glad it was resolved. Now, in order to close your question, accept **"YOUR" answer** and not the other one given, because that just wouldn't be right/fair. My guiding you did (*or most likely*) lead you to double check everything. I'm not in this for the points, so don't get me wrong. I just don't want somebody else to get the credit for it. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. My email input was named "mail", while my php was "email". Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Just as [`my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619255/unknown-sender-or-different-email-address-in-email-header#comment34444752_22619255) stated, which in its own right, should have been an answer.

Comment: If you ever have an issue like this again, the first thing is to dump all the variables and make sure they match. You can `var_dump` or `print_r`, also you should use `isset()` functions to make sure those values actually exist so you don't get undefined variable errors.

Comment: if this is the answer, you should accept it as such so that the question appears resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Use this;

```
$headers = 'From: ' . $visitor_email . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $visitor_email . "\r\n";
```

Comment: I am still getting the same result (unknown sender).  Thanks though

Comment: @C.Coggins Have you ever checked `$visitor_email` value?

Comment: How would I check that value?  When I hard coded it, it works.  Must be the problem, but I don't know how to check it.

Comment: you can use `var_dump($visitor_email);`